# How to implement username:password@domain.ext HTTP authentication in Windows Phone WebView

Tags: http, authentication, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, basic-authentication

In Internet Explorer, this HTTP URL format for authentication is not allowed:

***username:password@domain.com***

However, in Visual Studio 2013, the ***WebBrowser* control** allows this on desktop apps, but the ***WebView* control** for Windows Phone apps does not.

How could this be done in Windows Phone apps?

Thank you.

Comment: no, ie hasn't disabled http authentication. that'd break the interwebz. they disabled embedding credentials in the url.

Comment: My mistake. How do we work around this embedding of credentials? The server _(third party)_ only accepts this type of authentication. Otherwise, a login pop-up would appear?